# rJava 0.9-11 is not available (for R version 3.6.1)

Tags: java, rstudio, rjava, xlconnect, homebrew-cask

i have a problem installing rJava on my Mac. I installed Homebrew, atom and java before because I want to create an excel data with the package XLConnect. In the description was written I have now to install rJava. When I want to install the package with the code:

install.packages("https://cran.r-project.org/src/contrib/Archive/rJava/rJava_0.9-11.tar.gz")

the following error escapes in the Console of R Studio:

Warning in install.packages :
  package 'https://cran.r-project.org/src/contrib/Archive/rJava/rJava_0.9-11.tar.gz' is not available (for R version 3.6.1)

Does anyone have an idea to solve the problem? I would be very thankful.

PS: Excuse my bad English.

Comment: https://www.owsiak.org/r-3-4-rjava-macos-and-even-more-mess/ https://www.owsiak.org/r-java-11-and-making-sure-you-can-load-rjava/